# .NET Core and Framework apps with a shared .NET Standard BL library

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-core, .net-standard

I have to design a new set off applications, both web as Windows, that use shared functionality.

Preferably, they want to use .NET Core for the web application, but the Windows client has to be in .NET Framework as Core is not yet suitable to make a Desktop app with, certainly if it has to support older Windows versions (till 7).

Now it seems you can create a .NET Standard class library that is usable by both Core as Framework.
This made me think, can't I write all shared business logic and data access in a .NET Standard library and just have the Web and Windows apps be no more than a GUI and some minor logic to control the GUI?

Most of it will be using Entity Framework to connect to the DBs, SQL Server for the web app and SQL Compact for the desktop app, and Entity Framework Core is supported in both Framework as Core. So first of all can I use it in the Standard library, knowing that both DBs have the same structure (the Client DB will be an export of the Server DB)?
If so, are there any limitations for putting this in a Standard project?

Are there any limitations to LinQ in the Standard support?

And lastly, does Standard have support for printing?

If all of this isn't possible, we'll put everything in .NET Framework, but it'd be nice to prepare for the future as it seems everything will be moving to Core.

Keeping the logic online and having the Client access it through services isn't an option, we need to have the client working in an offline environment.

Comment: I rather say why not give it a try. All the things you asked can be easily tested out and you can then give an answer yourself.

Comment: Why would you include *printing* in "shared business logic and data access"? That sounds much more like a UI concern...

Comment: .NET Standard's purpose is to ease the pain of sharing code between .NET implementations, so just put any shared logic inside .NET Standard libraries and any specific code (e.g. printing) into their relevant applications.

Comment: @John: Printing is one of the main functionalities of the system and has to be supported on all software varieties, therefore I'd want to put that logic in a shared location. Maybe my phrasing was a bit off, but I generally want everything in a shared functionality library that's not specific to one application variety.